# style list with delete button

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="name in itemArray">
        {{ name }}
            <button id="deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteItem (item)">X</button>
    </li>

</ol>
```

Yes, it's got AngularJS in it that pulls in info. It's a list with a delete button next to each list item, problem is, the delete button is -right- next to the list item, I'd like them to have some space, but nothing I do seems to work. I didn't bother adding the css here, as there's really nothing to add.

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin-left to the button. In your css you would have something like this:

```
#deleteBtn {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddlse](http://jsfiddle.net/Bn86Y/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="name in itemArray">
        {{ name }}
            <button id="deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteItem (item)">X</button>
    </li>

</ol>
```

CSS:

```
#deleteBtn {
    float: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lde87/)

Comment: That works for the most part, but it makes everything like steps.

Comment: How so? Please explain.

Comment: Instead of it all lining up nice and vertical, it turns the list and delete buttons into something more like steps. Sorry, I'm new to this, I don't know how I can use the return button without it posting my comment to demonstrate

Comment: I should note I'm testing in FF, but I just looked in Chrome and it looks even more terrible. It did appear fine in JSFiddle.

Comment: You have other HTML or CSS affecting it. Strip it away until you determine what it is.

Comment: I put all the HTML/CSS in JSFiddle, looked at the full screen result, and it also looked fine. I don't understand. http://jsfiddle.net/Lde87/

Comment: You provided me with the exact same link. You need to update the fiddle.

Comment: that fixes the list itself from stepping since it's aligned all the way to the left, but it still does the weird stepping with delete button, it's the weirdest thing.

Comment: using a left margin on the delete buttons seems to work much better, but then they are in line vertically.